# How to retrieve url for images from this site using DOM and JSOUP?

Tags: android, dom

If you click on this link you will see a list of titles.

[Titles](http://www.gamespy.com/index/release.htm)

If you click on any of the titles you will see a image for the title some were on the page.

What i would like to do is retrieve the url for the images on ANY of the titles no matter which one it is, the image url will still be retrieved by the common selector.

I have an idea of how it should be done...

Something like

```
Document doc = null;
doc = Jsoup.connect(url);
```

What should be next to get this information?

```
Element png = doc.select(//What should the tag be?);
```

I think i am on the right track.

A little help would be useful.

EDIT:

```
  try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get(); 

                } catch (IOException e) {

                   Log.e("ReleaseInfo", "JSoup get didnt get a document", e);

                }

                if(doc != null){
                       overview = doc.select("div#object-overview").last();
               //Tried to retrieve image url here   
                       Elements png = doc.select("a.b1");
                       Toast.makeText(getActivity(), png.text(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the  tag, you can identify them by their class name...

```
<a href="http://ps3.gamespy.com/playstation-3/deus-ex-3/" class="b1">  
        <em>Deus Ex: Human Revolution</em>
</a>
```

You can select them by element and then class like this...

```
Element png = doc.select("a.b1");
```

Comment: Okay cool! So that should get the URL for the images on any of the items in the list? With the common selector looking for the css class "a.b1"?

Comment: Also could i use "a.em" tag to retreive the title?